# How to bring View to top of UIView Hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview

My app currently has a search bar and generates a holder view of results dropping down from the search bar. However, the ResultContainerView is behind my other Views. I am wondering how to bring that search bar container view to the top of the UIView hierarchy. I tried using `[super bringSubviewToFront:_searchResultsHolderView];`
 but that did not work. Here is my method for when the searchbar is tapped.

```
- (void)_expandSearchResults
{
    CCLogVerbose (@"");
    _searchResultsHolderView.alpha = 0.0;
    _searchResultsHolderView.hidden = NO;
    [_searchResultsHolderView setFrameHeight:10];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"expandSearchResults" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:kAnimationDuration_SearchResults];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector (searchAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    _searchResultsHolderView.alpha = 1.0;
    [_searchResultsHolderView setFrameHeight:_searchResultsHt];
    [super bringSubviewToFront:_searchResultsHolderView];

    [UIView commitAnimations];  // start animation
}
```

And this is my reloadData method:

```
- (void)_reloadSearchResults:(NSString *)searchS
{
    CCLogVerbose (@"");
    if ([searchS length] == 0) {
        _searchResults = nil;
        [_searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        return;
    }

    NSAssert (self.patientService != nil, @"The Patient Service is invalid");
    [self.patientService searchPatients:searchS
        expandType:AllPatientExpansions
        success:^(NSArray *list) {
          _searchResults = list;
          [_searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        }
        failure:^(NSError *error) {
          CCLogDebug (@"Failed: %@", error);
        }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:_searchResultsHolderView];
```

First you need to bring `self` to the top of the stack. After that you can call `bringSubViewToFront` and bring your `_searchResultsHolderView` to the front.